# Issues with finding a WebElement in Google chrome

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, element

I am trying to find the element for a button in the webpage but cant seem to locate it. Usually I would use `.find_element_by_css_selector` and find the code. But now since they only gave the class, I tried another method which was to search up the hierarchy. Hence I used `browser.find_element_by_css_selector('div[class="btn-grp"]')` and I managed to locate the button group. But i cant seem to move down the hierarchy to the button.

[Image when inspecting the elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIhJI.png)

By the way, the website is https://form.gov.sg/#!/signin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for Get Started button to click and have this CSS selector `div[class="btn-grp"]`

You can move down like this :

```
div[class="btn-grp"] button
```

**In Selenium :**

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("div[class="btn-grp"] button")
```

Comment: Thanks!! I got it.